# Drop all temporary tables for an instance

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I was wondering how / if it's possible to have a query which drops all temporary tables?

I've been trying to work something out using the tempdb.sys.tables, but am struggling to format the name column to make it something that can then be dropped - another factor making things a bit trickier is that often the temp table names contain a '_' which means doing a replace becomes a bit more fiddly (for me at least!)

Is there anything I can use that will drop all temp tables (local or global) without having to drop them all individually on a named basis?

Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The point of temporary tables is that they are.. temporary. As soon as they go out of scope

- #temp create in stored proc : stored proc exits
- #temp created in session : session disconnects
- ##temp : session that created it disconnects

The query disappears.  If you find that you need to remove temporary tables manually, you need to revisit how you are using them.

For the global ones, this will generate and execute the statement to drop them all.

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
select @sql = isnull(@sql+';', '') + 'drop table ' + quotename(name)
from tempdb..sysobjects
where name like '##%'
exec (@sql)
```

It is a bad idea to drop other sessions' [global] temp tables though.

For the local (*to this session*) temp tables, just disconnect and reconnect again.

Comment: This is usefull when you are developing. When an error occurs, the temp tables are not dropped, disrupting the fix-and-test flow while in the session. So yea, this answer worth for #temp too.

Answer (score 15):

The version below avoids all of the hassles of dealing with the `'_'`s.  I just wanted to get rid of non-global temp tables, hence the `'#[^#]%'` in my `WHERE` clause, drop the `[^#]` if you want to drop global temp tables as well, or use a `'##%'` if you *only* want to drop global temp tables.

The `DROP` statement seems happy to take the full name with the `'_'`, etc., so we don't need to manipulate and edit these. The `OBJECT_ID(...) NOT NULL` allows me to avoid tables that were not created by my session, presumably since these tables should not be 'visible' to me, they come back with NULL from this call.  The `QUOTENAME` is needed to make sure the name is correctly quoted / escaped.  If you have no temp tables, `@d_sql` will be the empty string still, so we check for that before printing / executing.

```
DECLARE @d_sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @d_sql = ''

SELECT @d_sql = @d_sql + 'DROP TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(name) + ';
'
FROM tempdb..sysobjects
WHERE name like '#[^#]%'
AND OBJECT_ID('tempdb..'+QUOTENAME(name)) IS NOT NULL

IF @d_sql <> ''
BEGIN
    PRINT @d_sql
    -- EXEC( @d_sql )
END
```

Comment: Somewhat surprising that `DROP TABLE [#bar______ ... __00000000000F];` works. I would have previously imagined that it would only work with the friendly name `DROP TABLE  #bar`

Comment: Great answer, my favourite here.

Btw if you enjoy minimizing your T-SQL code, replace the declaration line with:

    DECLARE @d_sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'a:;';
 
then drop the final IF... block completely (lust leave the EXEC line)

Answer (score 7):

In a stored procedure they are dropped automatically when the execution of the proc completes.

I normally come across the desire for this when I copy code out of a stored procedure to debug part of it and the stored proc does not contain the `drop table` commands.

Closing and reopening the connection works as stated in the accepted answer. Rather than doing this manually after each execution you can enable SQLCMD mode on the Query menu in SSMS

[image]

And then use the `:connect` command (adjust to your server/instance name)

```
:connect (local)\SQL2014

create table #foo(x int)

create table #bar(x int)

select *
from #foo
```

Can be run multiple times without problems. The messages tab shows

> Connecting to (local)\SQL2014...
>
> (0 row(s) affected)
>
> Disconnecting connection from (local)\SQL2014...

Comment: I just wanted to mention that you could store RichardTheKiwi's SQL in a file (with a slight modification to also delete `#` tables too), say `C:\deleteTempTables.sql`, and invoke it using `:r C:\deleteTempTables.sql`.  The only advantage of this to Richard's solution is that it would take up one line only and can be easily (un)commented.