# How to get the current sproc session ID and drop a temp table existing in that sproc instance?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2000

I'm using sql2000 and I want to automatically drop a #temp table in a sproc instance or in a query window.  This is more for testing purposes than production.  Is there a way to get the current session or sproc instance or even a query instance, and use that to delete only #temp tables in that instance.  I don't want to drop #temp tables in other instances.

I noticed another Stack Overflow question used this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497450/drop-all-temporary-tables-for-an-instance):

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max) 
select @sql = isnull(@sql+';', '') + 
                                     'drop table ' + quotename(name) from tempdb..sysobjects 
where name like '#%' exec (@sql)
```

I just want to detect only #tmp tables in current session or instance.  I also will need to do this in sql2008. thx

Thanks.

Comment: Temporary tables are automatically dropped when they go out of scope. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/892351/sql-server-2005-and-temporary-table-scope

Comment: Mitch, I'm doing testing in a query window. They don't go out of scope in a query window where you are testing.  So I want to drop in some code, and drop all #temp tables and walla...no more temp tables.  I don't want to have to open a new query session each time b/c I'm very lazy.

Comment: Then I suspect you are using temp tables incorrectly...You should drop a temp table when no longer using it.

Comment: One other thing Mitch, I rely heavily on undo, that is my main reason for attempting to detect the query window session and drop only the #temp tables. (ie. the ones with only one #lb# sign.)

Comment: You must misunderstand, I don't want to manually drop one temp table.  I want to drop all of them.  Lets pretend I have 50 gazillion temp tables, I want to keep my undo feature, and I want to detect my current session and drop all of my temp tables. Walla... no long list of drop #temp1 drop #temp2 ....... I am open to new suggestions however if you have a better technique.

Comment: I gave you one pt for the link :)... but I really need to detect that session id.

Comment: I think its sp_who or sp_who2, but I'm not sure how to detect currently running query window or sproc.  This may be a EE (god forbid) question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your current SPID, again this works on 2005 and up I have not tested it on a 2000 instance

```
select @@SPID
```

shows what you are doing in that spid  workins in 2005 and up not sure about the 2000 version

```
dbcc inputbuffer(54)
```

Find spids and kernel threads before execute the test take a screen shot

```
   select spid, kpid, status, hostname, dbid, cmd
   from master..sysprocesses
```

Run the SQL again once you start your testing
 reference this site http://support.microsoft.com/kb/117559

To drop your temp table if you know the names  you can expand on this to get the desired result

```
IF object_ID('tempdb..#MyTempTable') is not null
begin
    drop table #MyTempTable
end


create table #MyTempTable
(id int);

insert into #MyTempTable (id) values (1);

select * from #MyTempTable

select * from tempdb.sys.tables
where object_id = object_id('tempdb..#MyTempTable')

IF object_ID('tempdb..#MyTempTable') is not null
begin
    drop table #MyTempTable
end
```

Comment: Just tested, @@SPID does work on sql2000.  I think I'll use that drop table, but I really want to drop all temp tables from my current @@SPID.  thx

Comment: I think this is the solution. When you create a temp table... set the first or second column with a column of spid to always equal to @@spid. Then use the system table tempdb..sysobjects where name like '#%' to give you a list of available... then search those that have a column named 'spid', and then amoung them search for the ones that = @@spid, and drop only those tables. Good job.

Answer (score 0):

Just KILL the process with the SPID that you are suspecting, and then all temp tables (local and global) will be dropped.

Comment: Shark, I don't know where my SPID is, or how to differentiate one SPID from another.  But once I do have that, I believe I can decide how to use it, but yeah I can see about several hundred of them in my sp_who2 and about 50 under my name.  I want to select only my currently running process.  I'm not interested in easter egging this.