# Dropping all local temp tables prior to running a query

Tags: sql-server-2012

I'm debugging a stored procedure by running various pieces of the code manually.  The problem is the code creates a lot of temp tables, so I have to add a lot of `"DROP TABLE #name"` to the start of my query in order for it to work for multiple runs.

Is there a way to drop all temp tables before my query runs?

Comment: Other than `DROP TABLE #t1, #t2, ...etc...;`? Or perhaps disconnecting and reconnecting? Nope.

Comment: @AaronBertrand thanks.  is there a way to disconnect/reconnect in code?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the solution in an old post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497450/drop-all-temporary-tables-for-an-instance) ...

I would suggest first make sure that its only deleting the table you want to delete, by print the query prepared

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max)

select @sql = isnull(@sql+';', '') + 'drop table ' + quotename(name)
from tempdb..sysobjects
where name like '##%'

select @sql
```

And then if all table names look good to you. Run with exec(SQL)

```
EXEC( @sql )
```

Below is the test I did for this, and it worked for because my temp tables has names starting with '##' which in my cases didn't pulled any global temp tables.

```
declare @sqlCreate nvarchar(max)
declare @sqldrop nvarchar(max)

--Creating Temp tables
set @sqlCreate = 'create table ##tempTable1( c int, b int, a nvarchar(50) ) ; create table ##tempTable2( c int, b int, a nvarchar(50) )'
EXEC( @sqlCreate )

--Preparing drop statement
select @sqldrop = isnull(@sqldrop+';', '') + 'drop table ' + quotename(name)
from tempdb..sysobjects
where name like '##%'

--Making sure that only my temp tables are returned.
select @sqldrop 

--Executing the drop query
EXEC(@sqldrop)
```

Comment: But that will try to drop #temp tables that exist in other user's sessions, too. I think the answer is to type - once - your list of tables in a drop command, and then put that at the beginning or the end of your script during debugging.

Comment: Well, actually, on further inspection: (a) it will only drop ##global temp tables, and it will try to do so using the full name (e.g. #a______hexcode vs. #a), which won't work, either.