# OBJECT_ID DROP #TEMP Table - multiple tables at once SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server

I had a question regarding dropping temp tables with:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.#Scores', 'U') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE dbo.#Scores
```

I have over 8 different #temp tables. Is there a way of writing the above code to include all these temp tables rather than having to write code for 7 tables:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.#Scores1', 'U') IS NOT NULL
      DROP TABLE dbo.#Scores1

IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.#Scores2', 'U') IS NOT NULL
          DROP TABLE dbo.#Scores2

IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.#Scores3', 'U') IS NOT NULL
          DROP TABLE dbo.#Scores4

IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.#Scores1', 'U') IS NOT NULL
          DROP TABLE dbo.#Scores4
```

Is there a way of including in all #temp tables in 4 lines of code?

Comment: Possible dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497450/drop-all-temporary-tables-for-an-instance

Answer (score 0):

You can include multiple tables in a `DROP TABLE` statement.

This will drop all that exist and raise an error for any that don't.

If you don't want those errors reported back you would need to use try..catch.

```
BEGIN TRY
      DROP TABLE #Scores1,
                 #Scores2,
                 #Scores3,
                 #Scores4,
                 #Scores5,
                 #Scores6,
                 #Scores7,
                 #Scores8
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

END CATCH
```